How can I create a dynamic library in assembly aarch64?
I have a problem, I am doing tests to understand how dynamic libraries work on Android, and I have created one in aarch64 assembler


.global printHello                                      

.section .text                                          

printHello:                                                     mov x8, #64

        mov x0, #1

        ldr x1, =buffer1

        mov x2, #14



        svc 0



        ret



.section .data

                                                        buffer1: .ascii "Hello, world!\n"

, I have compiled it with as LibTest.s -o LibTest.o and linked with ld LibTest.o -o libTest.so -shared, then I have created the main
.global _start



.extern printHello



.section .text



_start:

        bl printHello                                   

        mov x8, #93

        mov x0, #0      
        svc 0

, I have compiled it with as Main.s -o Main.o and linked with
ld -pie -dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker64 -L. -lTest Main, but when running it gives me this error CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "./Main.elf": "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/asm/libTest.so" has text relocations. I have tried putting the argument -fPIC in the linker, but it still gives me the same error.
I don't know what I need to do.

What error do you get?  Also, what operating system are you programming for?

I'm programming in android for be able to programming in aarch64 asm

-fPIC is a code generation option has no effect on the linker. It tells the compiler to produce position independent code. Since you are writing the assembly directly, you are the compiler, you should write PIC :) The problem is the ldr x1, =buffer1. Try adr x1, buffer1 instead.

While I agree with Jester, you might be even better off using adrp x0, buffer1@PAGE and then add x0, x0, buffer1@PAGEOFF.  The two sections may not end up being anywhere near each other in memory.
